# How to prevent white-space property inheritance?

Tags: html, css

My style is:

```
.Content > div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I want only first children of `.Content` being "no wrappable". But all divs inside first children becomes "no wrappable". This is not what I need. Is there a way to solve this problem?

**Edit**

My html is:

```
<div class="Content">
    <div class="left">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="center1">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="center2">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, I want only `.left`, `.center1`, `.center2`, `.right` divs being "no wrappable" inside `.Content` div.

Comment: Can you post html also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the children of the `.Content`'s children to not have the `white-space: nowrap;` property.

You can do this by using this css:

```
.Content > div > div {
    white-space: normal;
}
```